# How to update the Managed Metadata Field in Document Library for only .Zip Files using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, taxonomy

This code override the all old value with new value; I need a code to append the new value with old one.

```
<Code For Termset>
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy")
$site = Get-SPSite http://invi28apps9c
$session = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($site)
$termStore = $session.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"]
$group = $termStore.Groups["KB"]
$termSet = $group.TermSets["IPS Document type"]     
$terms = $termSet.GetTerms(100)
$term = $terms | ?{$_.Name -eq "Docset"}
```

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://invi28apps9c/DemoTeamSite
$list = $web.Lists["KBDocument"]

$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
 $query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";
$query.RowLimit = 2000
 $caml = "<Where> 
  <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='DocIcon'/>
     <Value Type='Computed'>.zip</Value>

  </Eq>
    </Where>"
 $query.Query = $caml 

  do
    {
$listItems = $list.GetItems($query)
$spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition

foreach($item in $listItems)
{

    $spItem = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem]$item;


    $taxField =     [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$spItem.Fields["Document Type"]


   $taxField.SetFieldValue($spItem,$term)
    $spItem.Update()
}
   }
  while ($spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
```

Comment: To append a new value onto an old one, you typically first store the old text value to a variable, then add on the new text value with `+=` or other text appending method. Is this what you mean?

Comment: these fields are not text field these are managed metadata field so give the code for that.

Comment: Hi Lokesh. In case you are not aware, _Stack Overflow_ is not a free coding service where requirements can be set and then an answer must be delivered "ASAP". Your code here is a good start, but would you next outline where you are stuck? What have you tried to do the append operation?

Answer (score 0):

When you access the value of the field, you should receive a [TaxonomyFieldValueCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfield.getfieldvalue.aspx) object. This object has an `Add()` method you can use to add terms to it.

```
$value = $spItem["Document Type"]
$value.Add($term)
$spItem["Document Type"] = $value
$spItem.Update()
```